# Is there any way to sort in digiKam by a specific metadata tag?

Tags: digikam

All my files in my image and video library use `XMP::photoshop\DateCreated\DateCreated\0`. When I open my library in digiKam and do view by creation date, the order is incorrect.

I'm not exactly sure how digiKam is sorting, but I don't want to have to retag my whole library to whatever system they use. Is there any way to tell digiKam to sort by `XMP::photoshop\DateCreated\DateCreated\0`, which is Date Subject Created.

Comment: In what way is the sort order incorrect? Are the images being sorted by the order the files  were created *on your computer* and you want them sorted by the order they were taken with the camera? Or are the images being ordered by the date and time they were taken and you want them sorted by the order each file was created on your computer? Something else?

Comment: The sorting by EXIF DateTimeOriginal doesn't use the time zone (OffsetTimeOriginal), so photos taken in different time zones can appear out of order. XMP DateCreated DOES use the time zone (which is included as part of the DateCreated string), so photos appear chronologically even when taken in different time zones.

Comment: I think you need to fix the typo in your question. The tag you say PS is currently using is identical to the tag you say you wish to use...

Comment: What is PS? If you mean Photoshop, that's not what I am using. I am using the digiKam program.

Comment: Okay, digiKam. The fact remains. The two tags in your question are identical. If you want digiKam to sort using a different tag, you need to use a different tag.